# Clicking a button in one of the window creates a label in the other window

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a python tkinter app with multiple windows.

I want to be be able to click a button widget (`message_button`) in one of the windows (`PageOne`), and have it print a message using a label widget in the other window (`PageTwo`).

I've attempted it with my `message_fun()` (see below), but I can only manage to place the label in the same window (`PageOne`).

I've also tried changing `self` to `PageTwo` in `message_fun()`, but that only gives me an error message *AttributeError: type object 'PageTwo' has no attribute 'tk'*.

Thanks for any help!

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk

class MyPages(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):   

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        title_label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page one", font=("Verdana", 12))
        title_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        navigate_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Two", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        navigate_button.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
    
        message_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Message button", command= self.message_fun)
        message_button.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

    def message_fun(self):    
        message_label = tk.Label(self, text='I want this message in page two', font=("Verdana", 12))
        message_label.pack(side = tk.LEFT)  

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):  

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)        
        title_label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page two", font=("Verdana", 12))
        title_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        navigate_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Page one", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        navigate_button.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
    

app = MyPages()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `self.controller.frames[PageTwo]` instead of `self`, but you need to save `controller` to `self.controller` inside `__init__()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `Page` gets as second argument `controller` which gives access to `MyPages` and `MyPages` has `frames` which gives access to all pages.

So you should first in `__init__` keep `controller` as `self.controller`, and next you can use `self.controller.frames[PageTwo]` to access second page in first page.

```
    tk.Label(self.controller.frames[PageTwo], ...
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk

class MyPages(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):   

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.controller = controller
        
        title_label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page one", font=("Verdana", 12))
        title_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        navigate_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Two", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        navigate_button.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
    
        message_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Message button", command= self.message_fun)
        message_button.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

    def message_fun(self):    
        message_label = tk.Label(self.controller.frames[PageTwo], text='I want this message in page two', font=("Verdana", 12))
        message_label.pack(side = tk.LEFT)  

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):  

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)        

        self.controller = controller

        title_label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page two", font=("Verdana", 12))
        title_label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        navigate_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Page one", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        navigate_button.pack(side = tk.LEFT)
    

app = MyPages()
app.mainloop()
``
```